# warning when adding event listener to turn based ios game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, gamekit

here is the code in gamekithelper.m

```
- (void)authenticateLocalPlayer
{

     //1
     GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

     //add a weak local player
     __weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;

     if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LocalPlayerIsAuthenticated object:nil];
         return;
     }

     //2
     localPlayer.authenticateHandler  =
     ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
         //3
         [self setLastError:error];

         if(viewController != nil) {
             //4
             [self setAuthenticationViewController:viewController];


             *******problem code************
             // add event handler
             [blockLocalPlayer registerListener:self];

         } else if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
             //5
             _enableGameCenter = YES;
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LocalPlayerIsAuthenticated object:nil];

              *******problem code************
             // add event handler
             [blockLocalPlayer registerListener:self];

         } else {
             //6
             _enableGameCenter = NO;
         }
     };

}
```

here is the @interface in gamekithelper.h

```
@interface GameKitHelper : NSObject <GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKTurnBasedEventListener>
```

here is the warning

```
Sending 'GameKitHelper *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<GKLocalPlayerListener>'
```

I feel like I am making an easily fixable mistake but I can't figure out what it is, can any of you help me out?

Extra info

- I am doing this in spritekit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[blockLocalPlayer registerListener:self];
```

This method accepts an object that conforms to the protocol `GKLocalPlayerListener`. As you can see in your interface, `GameKitHelper` does not state that it conforms to the `GKLocalPlayerListener` protocol.

You should add the declaration of conformance to `GKLocalPlayerListener` by changing this:

```c
@interface GameKitHelper : NSObject <GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKTurnBasedEventListener>
```

to this:

```c
@interface GameKitHelper : NSObject <GKLocalPlayerListener, GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKTurnBasedEventListener>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed it