# How to detect when Game Center turn based match has ended in iOS9?

Tags: ios, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm totally lost with how to implement a turn-based game. I've been trying to use the `GKLocalPlayerListener` methods to handle turn-based in iOS9. The only method that ever fires is `receivedTurnEventForMatch`, which leaves me with no method that I know of that calls an end game routine for each player. I am trying to handle turn-based matches inside of my app using the Game Center match maker view controller and delegate methods. I read that `GKLocalPlayerListener` methods work for matches when going through the actual Game Center app (Apple docs don't mention this). So if that's true, then `GKLocalPlayerListener` is not an option for my app?

What can I do to detect when a match ends? I want to keep a win-lose record for each player, so it's important that a routine is called for each player when a match ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifecycle of a turn based match looks like this:

1. Create a match
2. Invite others
3. Others join
4. Players take turns and pass the match object around (your game logic decides the order)
5. Players send exchanges back and forth (optional)
6. Players start leaving
7. ----because they have been eliminated
8. ----because they quit
9. ----because they timed out
10. Someone Wins

If you are not the active player, you are notified when steps 3, 4, 7, 8 and 9 happen by `playerReceivedTurnEventForMatch` firing; however, as you can see from my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458493/1641444 `playerReceivedTurnEventForMatch` fires for a lot of different conditions, and it doesn't tell you which one triggered it. You have to discern that based on the status of the players, which player is the active player, and whatever other information you track in the match object.

You are notified of #5 by `playerReceivedExchangeRequest` firing (and Replies and Cancellation functions).

Your game logic will decide when to trigger #7. My preference is that the match object comes to the eliminated player, they are recognized as defeated, and calls `participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome`

Players decide when to trigger #8 by quitting, and the code calls either `participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome` or `participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome` depending on their state.

Condition #9 is a real pain in the ass. Between limitations in the game design and outright bugs, timeouts can create several unrecoverable edge cases. Handling timeouts warrants its own full answer.

Finally, #10 is triggered by calling `endMatchInTurnWithMatchData`. `GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate` and `handleMatchEnded` were deprecated in IOS7. When using `GKLocalPlayerListner`, you'll be notified of #10 by yet another occurrence of `playerReceivedTurnEventForMatch`

Edit--Clarifications based on followup questions:

Yeah, exactly. In your sendTurn function, when the game is over, don't call `endTurnWithNextParticipant`. Instead, set the each participant's status to indicate who won and who lost, and then call `endMatchInTurnWithMatchData`.

The other players will see `playerReceivedTurnEventForMatch` fire. You can discern from the match status and the player status that the game is over and decide what actions to take for that recipient.

Comment: Thanks Thunk, I've read several of your other answers on SO. Very insightful. My endMatchInTurnWithMatchData is in my sendTurn method, so are you saying when that is fired for any player it should also yield the occurrence of player:receivedTurnEventForMatch? Which then I can handle my end-game methods in that GKLocalPlayerListener method, given that the match is over (check using if statement or something)?

Comment: @codeflow, thanks for the kind words. Yeah, exactly. I updated the answer to be a little more clear about that.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I know this is a bit unrelated to my original question, but might you have any inkling as to why receivedTurnEventForMatch is the only method that fires? If it helps, I have used this approach to add GKLocalPlayerListener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971430/warning-when-adding-event-listener-to-turn-based-ios-game

Comment: No, and I find it very frustrating. I've opened a bug, asking for an eventType parameter to be added to the function call so we know which of the ~dozen or so conditions triggered it. No response from Apple. Let me know if there's anything else I can add. If the posted answers have been helpful, please don't forget to vote/accept! :)

Comment: I will also enforce this bug you've submitted as that is an excellent addition and would eliminate the need to write a series of convoluted workarounds. Thanks!

Comment: @Thunk, do you know of any basic iOS 9 Turnbased example code? I swear no one uses this shitty API

Comment: @sdc, Unfortunately, I haven't seen anyone create any new tutorials on this. I'm currently studying the new stuff announced in IOS10 and will probably move from `GKTurnBasedMatch` to the game session stuff, as well.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue and im getting very frustrated.  
 
Bundle ID register to Gamecenter + Notifications
I'm sending a endTurnWithNextParticipants with no errors
 
but I do not get a :
 
Push Notification on the other device
nor the GKTurnBasedEventListener functions are beeing called.

Answer (score 0):

To end a match, you should have your game call `endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler:`

If you've implemented `GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate` protocol on an object, your `handleMatchEnded` will get a push event.

More details in [Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW12)

Comment: Will the endMatchInTurnWithMatchData be called for all players? I need to add to a total number of games counter for each player so I need something that fires for each player regardless if they're currently playing. Also is it really wise to use handleMatchEnded since GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate is deprecated?